# Get google search first result with Goutte

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the first result url of google search using Goutte PHP library, sadly I haven't found many info on how to get a list of results from google using Goutte...

I'm using laravel and I already installed Guzzle and Goutte libraries with composer.

```
public function getGoogleResults(Request $request)
    {
        // Extract and sanatize input:
        $domain = $request->input('domain');
        $terms = $request->input('terms');
        
        // Build up a search URL:
        $pages = 10;
        $url = 'http://www.google.es/search?'.http_build_query(array('q' => $terms));
        
            // Request search results:
        $client = new Goutte\Client;
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this laravel package to get the first result.
[jdrda/laravel-google-custom-search-engine](https://github.com/jdrda/laravel-google-custom-search-engine)

Comment: I think this one uses Google Custom Search API which free tier is pretty limited